# Show a ResultSet (not a cursor) in Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, resultset, simplecursoradapter

I got a result from remote database as a Result set like this:

```
String queryString = "select n as name, a as address from sometable";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(queryString);
```

I want to show in a ListView some data: a name, an address from this result and a checkbox for user to check some lines. The lines checked will be saved in a local dadabase (SQLite) to work with further.

Please, help me to find an answer to these:

How should I use ResultSet to show in ListView, I read that to use a SimpleCursorAdapter I should have a Cusor, not a ResultSet. How can I convert ResultSet into Cursor?

And another question. Do I need to have 1 extra field for checkbox (for example "ch_")? If user press an item in a list, do it change the value in "ch_"?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could convert your `ResultSet` into `ArrayList` of your customized object, then instead of using `SimpleCursorAdapter` , you could extend from `BaseAdapter` to utilize the list data.

Answer (score 0):

If `rs` is a Cursor, then looking at your query you get name `rs.getString(0)` and address `rs.getString(1)`.

About second question what do you need this checkbox for?

Comment: I will get some data from remote table, user will check rows that he want to get, I will place this rows in local table (sqlite) and will use them further for another actions. that is why I thought that I need extra field boolean.

Comment: I have never worked with ResultSet but in here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29 you can see that it has methon getString(int). Have you tried it?

Comment: So I shoul try to pass data from ResultSet to Cursor line by line? I am sorry I compleatly new in java and android.